# Texmaker asks about document encoding everytime I open a document

Tags: 16.04, language-support, latex, encoding

Every time I open a document in Texmaker it says:

> It seems that this file cannot be correctly decoded with the default encoding setting (UTF-8). Use this encoding:

and it suggests **ISO-8859-1** which I accept and everything is OK in the world. It just annoys me that it has to ask every time I open a document.

Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the system language is English but the keyboard is Spanish (I like it that way because my mother tongue is Spanish but it is easier to search for errors or installation steps in English). I also write latex documents in both languages.

If somebody could tell me how to get rid of the message and explain to me 
why it is appearing, I would be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

My specs:

```
*Texmaker 4.4.1
*OS: Ubuntu 16.04
*kernel: 4.12.0-041200-generic
*Laptop Model: ASUS ROG Strix GL753VD
```

Comment: Did you set ISO-8859-1 encoding in “Configure Texmaker” → “Editor” → “Editor Font Encoding”?

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue. I remembered though that I did that once and had problems with á, é, í, ó, ú and ñ. Right now I'm writing a document in English. I hope it's not an issue when I switch to Spanish. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Texmaker documentation](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html) says:

> Before compiling your first document, you must set the encoding used by the editor ("Configure Texmaker" -> "Editor" -> "Editor Font Encoding"). Then, you should use the same encoding in the preamble of yours TeX documents (example : \usepackage[latin]{inputenc}, if you use the "ISO-8859-1" encoding for the editor).
>
> Note: while opening a file, you're warned if the document can't be decoded correctly with the default encoding and the program lets you choose an other encoding (without modifying the default encoding).

From your statements I assume you have set `UTF-8` as your default encoding and just need to set the encoding in the above mentioned way to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default encoding for Texmaker by following these steps:

1. Open Texmaker
2. Go to the "Options" menu
3. Select "Configure Texmaker"
4. Go to the "Editor" tab
5. In the "Default Encoding" section, select the encoding you want to use.(UTF-8)
6. Click "OK"